# curl works at the command line, but how do i put it in a php file?

Tags: php, curl

The following curl format works for me from the command line.  The line below is just sample data, but the format works.

curl -u email@email.com:1234567 https://api.email.com/status

How do I transfer this into a php file so I can run it within php so I can analyze the result?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [PHP's built-in support for libcurl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

For authentication set a `CURLOPT_USERPWD` value using [curl_setopt()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)